# How to reset the recyclerview item after swiping using ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerviewitem , on swiping left side , I am creating an image on the top of recyclerview item with the following code ,I am able to get the image on the top of the item but I am unable to reset the recyclerviewitem after swiping , rather its clearing the entire item

Code :

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT){

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView arg0,
                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder arg1,
                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }


            public void onChildDraw(android.graphics.Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

                if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE && isCurrentlyActive) {
                    // Get RecyclerView item from the ViewHolder
                    View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;





                    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.swipeleft);
                    d.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), (int) dX, itemView.getBottom());
                    d.draw(c);


                }
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

            };

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(
                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                    int Swipedir) {




            }

        };
```

Comment: By saying reset, you mean undelete it?

Comment: I have resolved my self .Thanks for the response

Comment: Great! congrats, when you have time, share your answer, may help some people later ;)

Comment: How did you solve your problem? Can you elaborate? I have the same problem.